# Serializing data using XmlArrayItemAttribute not working well

Tags: wcf, serialization, .net-4.0

I have this DataContract, which is an array of strings:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order = 19)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("CardNumber", typeof(string), IsNullable = false)]
[DataMember]
public string[] Cards {get; set; }
```

As I read, it should be serialized like this:

```
<Cards>
    <CardNumber>123123</CardNumber>
</Cards>
```

but I'm still getting:

```
<Cards>
    <string>123123</string>
</Cards>
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CollectionDataContract** instead.
First, create a class:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="CardNumber")]
public class CardsList : List<string> { }
```

And then, replace this line:

```
[DataMember]
public string[] Cards {get; set; }
```

By this:

```
[DataMember(Name="Cards")]
public CardsList Cards {get; set; };
```

Hope it helps.