# WCF ArrayOfAnyType - what is this and why is it generated from an ArrayList in the WSDL definition?

Tags: c#, wcf

Within a [DataContract] on my WCF service I have defined:

```
[DataMember]
public ArrayList attributeNames {get; set;}
```

And the resulting definition in my WSDL file looks like this:

```
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" minOccurs="0" name="attributeNames" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfanyType"/>
```

On my client, however, that type is being recognized as `object[]`. Why is this? And how do I consume an `ArrayList` [DataMember] from a client if it is typed as `object[]`?

I've seen this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e9342aae-4045-434c-a830-ea89451a8e0d/convert-arrayofanytype-web-service-to-arraylist?forum=csharpgeneral

But I'm not sure how generics could help me here...

Comment: Based on the name `attributeNames` I guess the arraylist contains strings. Correct? If so, a `List <string>` would probably be easier to work with, and your client would have a `string[]` or possibly a `List <string>` depending on how you generated the client proxy class.

Comment: You can use `List<typeOfYourArray>`, or create a `CollectionDataContract`, read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586165/serializing-data-using-xmlarrayitemattribute-not-working-well/37592775#37592775

Comment: @user1429080 thank you for the reply. I actually have another variable called 'attributeValues' that may be of different types within the same list / array

Comment: Using an `ArrayList` here can be tricky. Since you can add any type of object into an arraylist, the client *will* be receiving just objects. You might be able to force the client to have a `List<object>` instead of the `object[]` though. But in any case, you can get into troubles because the `ArrayList` happily accepts any type of object, including objects that are not serializable and therefore cannot be returned from a webservice. I suggest you take a step back and redesign the service so it can return stongly typed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) ArrayList is just a list of generic objects.  That is basically the same thing as Object[].  What generics can do for you here is allow you to have one endpoint (or function) that can accept different objects.  Using ArrayList tells me that You may be returning different objects depending on the logic.  The calling end of your api needs to be able to handle that if you are going to be using genarics.

Comment: The ArrayList will be a list of varying objects, not necessarily the same type per list. Would generics such as List<T> allow for this?

Comment: With ArrayList you are correct, every item could be of a different type.  As for a List<T>, T is the type that is defined by the calling method and or declaration, so there is one type specified, not multiples.